# "Error: No table entry for 64" when compiling C program using cc

Tags: c, minix

I get this error when I try to compile C program in minix 203 using cc compiler. Minix is run from image using qemu on ubuntu 14.04. Does anyone know what that can mean and what to do to compile it succesfully?
Regards,
Andrzej

Comment: Could you paste C source of this? Does it compile with basic "HelloWorld"?

Comment: Is your Ubuntu 32-bit or 64-bit?  What about the Minix inside qemu?

Comment: Thanks guys for looking at it, I have solved the problem. The issue was quite simple, the code was waiting for value from function which is returning void. Stupid mistake...